# Manipulate with Locator question

Tags: manipulate, locator

Here is an example from Mathematica's help:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Polygon[pt], PlotRange -> 2], 
{{pt, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}}}, Locator}]
```

When I execute this, I can drag any `Locator`, and the `Polygon` changes.

Is there a way to access which element of `pt` is being dragged? So I could have a line in the code that does something different while different points are being dragged? Something like:

```
Manipulate[doSomethingIfPt2IsBeingDragged;Graphics[Polygon[pt], PlotRange -> 2], 
{{pt, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}}}, Locator}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you access it using the construct `pt[[pos]]`, where "pos" specifies the position of the element in the list of the locator points. In the case at hand it is the list `{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}}`. Its second element, `{1,0}`, for example is given by `pt[[2]]`, while the first subelement of the second element (i.e. `1`) - by `pt[[2,1]]`. Try the following as an example.  It draws a parametric plot changing as soon as you pull the second and/or the fifth locator:

```
 Manipulate[
 Column[{Graphics[Polygon[pt], PlotRange -> 2],
   ParametricPlot[{Cos[pt[[2, 1]]*t], Sin[pt[[5, 2]]*t]}, {t, 0, 
     2 \[Pi]}]
   }], {{pt, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This change the color of the polygon (only) while you're dragging it:

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic[
  Graphics[{Extract[{Black, Red, Green, Blue}, 
                     Last@Position[col, Except[0.], {1}] + 1], Polygon[pt]}, 
           PlotRange -> 2],
  (col = Total /@ (ptsave - pt); ptsave = pt)],
 {{pt, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}}, Locator},
 Initialization :> (ptsave = pt)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been doing something like that. I was just wondering if there was a cleaner (built-in) way to access which point was being dragged.